# Linq to SQL: Creating a complex object from many tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to know how to get an object.

I've got 3 tables:

```
Categories -
 -- Category_ID
 -- Category_Deleted
 -- Category_Date_Creation

Languages
 -- Language_ID
 -- Language_Code
 -- Language_Name

Category_Names
 -- Category_ID
 -- Language_ID
 -- Category_Name_Value
```

From these tables i've created a classes:

```
 public class Language
 {
      public int Id;
      public string Code;
      public string Name;

      public static Language Covert(DataContext.Language lang)
      {
           return new Language() { Id = lang.Id, Code = lang.Code, Name = lang.Name }
      }
 }

 public class Catigory
 {
      public int Id;
      public DateTime DateCreation;
      public Dictionary<Language, string> Names;
 }
```

Now i do something like this:

```
 Catigory cat = (from catigory in DataContext.Categories where catigory.Id == ID 
      select new Catigory() { Id = catigory, DateCreation = catigory.DateCreation }).First();
 cat.Names = (from cn in DataContext.Category_Names 
             join l in DataContext.Languages on cn.Language_ID equals l.Language_ID
             where cn.Category_ID == cat.Id
             select new { Key = l, Val = cn.Category_Name_Value }).ToDictionary(ss => Language.Covert(ss.Key), ss => ss.Val);
```

So i want to create a Category object from Linq, only by one query.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first link? Don't you just want `DataContext.Categories.Where(category => category.Id == ID).First()`? Why are you creating an imperfect copy (omitting the `Deleted` property)?

Comment: @AndrewCoonce as you see, there is no Converter from DataContext.Categories to Catigory class. May be it was a mistake in question example, that i had to very close to each other classes (Catigory and DataContext.Categoriy), but they are not the same.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce in youre way it would be better like this 
`DataContext.Categories.First(category => category.Id == ID)`